# Do CSS variables work differently in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-variables

I am developing a web site and have optimized it for Firefox and Chrome. The project contains a style sheet called `base.css` which is included in all the pages, and which contains some global settings and definitions, including a list of variables which I use to store color values like such:

```
:root {
    --yellow-1: #fff8e3;
    --yellow-2: #ffe9a9;
}
```

and so on, and calling them like for example:

```
.a-class {
    background-color: var(--yellow-2);
}
```

When I look at the page in Edge, all the colors are missing, and when I use the DOM explorer, it marks all uses of the variables with red underlines. Does Edge not support CSS variables in this way? What can I do to work around this?

Comment: Is that a typo? When declared correctly, `--yellow-2: #ffe9a9;` works fine in Edge. Can you provide a test case that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: If you like to support Custom Properties in IE11, have a look at this Polyfill: https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties It works with less then 2kb minified and gzipped. And its not limited to :root declarations.

Comment: I have this issue in `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0` and all the variables show up but are crossed out.

Answer (score 4):

MS Edge does support CSS variables from EdgeHTML v15:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/03/24/css-custom-properties/

This is also backed up here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility

---

The syntax is as follows:

**Declaring a variable:**

```
element {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
}
```

**Using the variable:**

```
element {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when variables are added to root dynamically; e.g.
`
function addCSS(css){document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML=css;}

addCSS(":root {--color0: white;}");
`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I defined variables with opacity. In Chrome it worked fine, but in edge it didn't. After I removed opacity from declarations, it worked fine in Edge as well.

Answer (score -1):

I tried isolating the problem, and it seems there were no problem with this in Edge. Normal CSS works works as supposed to.

When selecting browser prefix elements like:

```
::-ms-track
::-ms-fill-lower
::-ms-fill-upper
::-ms-thumb
```

Variables does not work on theese.